# How to disable the feature Accelerated Database Recovery (ADR) in SQL Server 2019 Express edition?

Tags: sql-server-2019, sql-server-2019-express

Is there a way to disable the new feature Accelerated Database Recovery (ADR) in the SQL Server 2019 Express edition?

Comment: [Manage accelerated database recovery - To disable the ADR feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/accelerated-database-recovery-management?view=sql-server-ver16)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously on SQL Server 2019 Express edition the ADR feature is turned off by default

If I try to turn off the feature as follow

```
ALTER DATABASE databaseFoo SET ACCELERATED_DATABASE_RECOVERY = OFF;
```

the answer is:

> Commands completed successfully.

If I try to turn on the feature as follow

```
ALTER DATABASE databaseFoo SET ACCELERATED_DATABASE_RECOVERY = ON;
```

the answer is:

> Msg 12128, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> **Accelerated Database Recovery cannot be enabled on Express edition.**

> Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> ALTER DATABASE statement failed.

Conclusion: Within the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/accelerated-database-recovery-management?view=sql-server-ver16) (posted in comment by Larnu) chapter **Enabling and controlling ADR** the mentioned behavior that ADR is turned off by default in SQL Server 2019 corresponds as well for SQL Server 2019 Express edition.